# how to submit a set of checkbox values to single column in database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a div , with following checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="charger"/>  Charger &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="case"/> Case &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="headset"/> Headset &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="box"/> Box&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="usb"/> USB Cable &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="sim"/> SIM<br/>
```

I need to submit all the selected checkbox values into one column in db

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 

$type = $_POST['type'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$serial = $_POST['serial'];
$imei = $_POST['imei'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];


$sql3= "INSERT INTO devices (type, name, serial, imei, mobile) VALUES ('$type', '$name', '$serial', '$imei', '$mobile')";
mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Problem I face is if I select multiple chjeckbox, only one checkbox is getting saved. How can I save all the selected checbox values in one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `name="mobile[]"` instead.
this will submit all mobile checkboxes as array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="charger"/>  Charger &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="case"/> Case &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="headset"/> Headset &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="box"/> Box&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="usb"/> USB Cable &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="sim"/> SIM<br/>
```

your `$_POST` variable will contain all checked values. it will look like that

```
$_POST['mobile'] = array('charger', 'case', ...)
```

you can use `implode()` to join this array to a string. And add it that way

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail